# regex select special character

Tags: javascript, regex

on this text

```
O:) :) 3:)
```

i want regex select `:)` only .. not `3:)` or `o:)` .. etc

Comment: That's fantastic news. Really made my day!

Comment: what is the problem of that ?

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @KarimMamdouh above comments are related to the SO community. This community is composed of people who shares problems/solutions/attempts to solve problems/etc so, that's why the comment. This is not a community about "please solve my issue". People here post questions about a problem they have, the attempts they made to solve them and code they used, you question actually is not a question, it lacks everything lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\s(:\))
```

And grab the content from the capturing group

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/tW9tF2/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  `:)`
```

You can see the content group like:

```
var myString = "O:) :) 3:)";
var myRegexp = /\s(:\))/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);  // ":)"
```

Comment: this only "space" +  `:)` ,, i mean i have to add space before `:)` to catch it

Comment: @KarimMamdouh you have to grab the content from the capturing group by using `$1`. Take a look at the link I posted in the answer

Comment: example : hello world :) O:)
i want to replace :) by :D without change :) of O:)

Comment: You can use the regex I posted in the answer. Check this **[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/tW9tF2/3)**. If you want the code, go to `Code generator` section

Comment: i'm using regexp to replace string using javascript .. so if u put the string in the start of the line .. nothing replaced ! ..

Comment: @KarimMamdouh try changing `\s` by `\b`